# Изменение переменной в других элементах

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеется несколько элементов с классом .q1, у каждого есть переменная "a" со значением 1. Как сделать чтобы при клике по одному из элементов с классом .q1 у всех остальных переменная "a" изменила значение на 0. А у нажатой не менялась?

Попробовал так: ˅

```js
$('.q1').each(function() {
  var a = 1;
  $(this).click(function() {
    $('.q1').a = 0;
  });

});
```

Comment: Как у элементов может быть переменная?

Comment: Цикл each() проходит по всем элементам .q1. В анонимной функции каждого элемента есть переменная "a" разве не так?

Comment: Вы каждый раз создаёте новую переменную (`var a = `), которая уничтожается после завершения функции.

Comment: @Other Как уничтожается? если один раз вызвать события клика то, сработает одно действие, и при повторном нажатии сработает другое $('.q1').each(function(){ 

var a=1; 
$(this).click(function(){ 
if(a!=0){ 
    //одно действие
a=0; 
} 
else{ 
    //другое действие
a=1; 
} 
}); 
});

Comment: @PeGaS в редакторе сниппетов есть специальная кнопочка «привести в порядок». Она сильно облегчает чтение вашего кода и даёт +100 к реакции читателей. Не пренебрегайте =)

Comment: @Other а что комментарием-то? Похоже на ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, скромность взыграла :)

Comment: @Other а теперь уже поздно, задубликатили. )

Comment: @NickVolynkin, я не расстроен, помощь и в комментах - помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Ту переменную которые вы создали в анонимной функции так и останется внутри анонимной функции. Вам нужно обращаться через просто `a`.

Прочитайте пожалуйста полностью раздел
[Область видимости и замыкания](http://learn.javascript.ru/functions-closures)